# MySql query 2 records as 1 result

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have a table **address** and a table **route**.

Route stores 2 ids of Address and the distance between these Locations -> `idStart`, `idEnd`, `distance`.

```
+-------+-------+-----+--------+
|idRoute|idStart|idEnd|distance|
+-------+-------+-----+--------+
|0      |1      |3    |2698    |
|1      |2      |4    |914     |
+-------+-------|-----+--------+


+---------+---------+-------------+
|idAddress|country  |city         |
+---------+---------+-------------+
|0        |USA      |Indianapolis |
|1        |Brasil   |Rio          |
|2        |Germany  |Munich       |
|3        |Argentina|Buenos Aires |
|4        |Italy    |Rome         |
+---------+---------+-------------+
```

`

So i'd like to query and get all routes as follows:

```
+-------+-------+-------+--------+---------+------+------------+--------+
|idRoute|idStart|idEnd  |CountryS|CountryE |CityS |CityE       |distance|
+-------+-------+-------+--------+---------+------+------------+--------+
|0      |1      |3      |Brasil  |Argentina|Rio   |Buenos Aires|2698    |
|1      |2      |4      |Germany |Italy    |Munich|Rome        |914    |
+-------+-------+-------+--------+---------+------+------------+--------+
```

If i do some subqueries and outerquery a specific route id it'll work since i got a specific where id=#

```
       SELECT
            ro.idRoute,
            ro.idStart,
            ro.idEnd,
            ro.distance,
            ro.time,
            (select a.country from address a 
            left join route ro 
                on (a.idAddress=ro.idStart)
            WHERE ro.idRoute='.$id .') as country_start,
            (select a.country from address a 
            left join route ro 
                on (a.idAddress=ro.idEnd)
            WHERE ro.idRoute='.$id .') as country_end, FROM route ro
        LEFT JOIN address a ON (a.idAddress=ro.idStart)
        LEFT JOIN countries c ON (a.country=c.code)
        WHERE ro.idRoute='.$id . $this -> presetFilter . ';
```

But in most cases i'd need all records of route and i cant get this working since for the subqueries i would miss the where Statements.

Something like outer query -> "`set fieldname as outerResult`" and use outerResult in where Statement of inner query????

Comment: iguess `idAdress` matches with `idStart` and `idEnd`

Comment: In the question you wrote you have 2 tables, but the query has 3: there is a countries table listed there as well.

Comment: Anyhow, this is a duplicate question because you just need to join the address table twice. Perhaps the countries table twice as well.

Comment: Here's an idea. If you instead stored the coordinates, then you'd automatically have the distance between *every* pair of cities!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to join to address twice from route table: once for the IDstart and once for the IdEnd.  This is done by using table aliases so you can reference address table twice and when joining or referencing fields the database engine knows which reference to the table is used/needed.

```
SELECT r.IdRoute
     , r.idstart
     , r.idend
     , Start_Add.country as CountryS
     , End_Add.country CountryE
     , Start_Add.city as CityS
     , End_Add.city as CityE
     , r.distancce
FROM route r
INNER JOIN Address Start_Add
 on r.IDStart= Start_Add.IdAddress
INNER JOIN address End_Add
 on r.IDEnd= End_Add.IdAddress
```